# No buttons showing in jQuery pop ups

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using a dialog box and a date picker but for some reason there is no close button showing the top right corner and you cannot see the arrow buttons in the date picker. The buttons are there because the border shows when you hover over them but you cannot see them at any other time. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Border shows means you have loaded the css correctly. But buttons are missing because the button strip image is missing.

Check your css that the image strip path is given correctly. It has to relative to the css file.

You can debug more using Firebug in Firefox, or Inspect Element in chrome.